# Graph Api Facebook get 20 people who like, comment and share the most on a page in angular

Tags: facebook, angular, facebook-graph-api

I want to know if it's possible to get the 20 people of a page who like, comment and share the most on a facebook page.

I use angular 2 and 4 and the API Graph tool.

Thank u for ur help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that, but you can do it manually yourself. Like get the list of the likes , comments and shares on your different posts like this:

```js
FB.api(
  '/me',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"posts{likes,comments,shares}"},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

The above code gives you the list of the users who liked your facebook page's post, commented or shared it. Now you can iterate over these posts and now you can check the user which appear in most of the cases(cases - posts) i.e. the person who is more engaged in your posts. This way you can find your biggest fan of the page.